# How to call a constructor function with new

Tags: interop, ffi, rescript

I'm a new with ReScript. I try to use it with `Telegraf`. I imported telegraf:

```
@module("telegraf")
```

How I can call `Telegraf` constructor?

```js
let tg = new telegraf.Telegraf("bot_token")
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the `@new` annotation:

```ml
type t

@module("telegraf") @new
external telegraf: string => t = "Telegraf"

let tg = telegraf("")
```

generates

```js
var Telegraf = require("telegraf");
var tg = new Telegraf.Telegraf("");
```

[Playground](https://rescript-lang.org/try?code=C4TwDgpgBMBQsAEC2B7AJgVwDYQBQCJgIcBzAJwEMAzfASigQDsIB3WCADyLMYqxmIRy1AFxQAzsDIBLRiSgBeAHwxFUfABVBwmvBzAY8hQNKUqBOrCA)